# How do I make an object a property of a model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, model, properties, schema

I have this in my schema:

```
create_table "robots_matches", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "robot_id"
t.integer  "match_id"
```

and I think I want to be able to load a robot and match from within my robots_match model so I can do something like this:
robots_match.find(:id).get_robot().Name

My attempt in the robots_matches model was this:

```
def get_robot
Robot.find(this.id)
end
```

I am super new to rails, so feel free to correct my architectural decision here.

Comment: Please show your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider starting with the models below.
This allow a match to have many robots and also a robot to have many matches, via '`Linker`'.
Then you can do queries like `Robot.find(1).matches` or `Match.find(1).robots`

```
class Robot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many linkers
  has_many matches, :through => linkers

class Linker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :robots
  belongs_to :matches

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many linkers
  has_many robots, :through => linkers
```